# О написании некоторых заимствованных имен собственных

Tags: ономастика, орфография

В Казахстане город Чимкент с 1992 года переименовали в Шымкент. Однако такое написание не соответствует нормам русского языка. То же самое касается имени собственного Бухар Жырау. По-казахски пишется Жырау, но надо ли так же писать по-русски? Как правильно писать в таких случаях?

Answer (score 1):

Русский язык в Казахстане не является государственным, но конституцией официально признан для использования в гос. учреждениях наравне с казахским. Широта его использования привела к тому, что работы филологов на стыке языков (в частности, по практической транскрипции имён собственных) ведутся преимущественно в Казахстане, в интересах использования там русских вариантов наименований. Некоторые из таких работ направлены на пересмотр русской транскрипции уже устоявшихся наименований. Например, предлагается приблизить русское написание Байконура к казахскому произношению (Байконыр), а "живучесть" прежнего наименования обосновывают тем, что формально на период аренды у Байконура есть статус российского городка.

[http://www.kaznu.kz/content/files/pages/folder14360/Диссертация](http://www.kaznu.kz/content/files/pages/folder14360/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) Акшолаковой Асем Жаксыбековны.pdf

Вся проблема в том, насколько правомерно переносить нормы варианта русского языка, практикуемого и нормативно регламентируемого в Казахстане (или Белоруссии) на нормы собственно русского языка, который относительно устойчив в отношении перенятия чужих самоназваний, склонен к сохранению сложившихся (мы не говорим "Наполи", "Фьоренца", "Дженова"). При переносе названий в русский действуют как традиции, так и правила *практической транскрипции*, в основе которых лежит требование однозначности обратного перевода, а соответствие произношению и написанию (транслитерация) в сложных случаях находится на втором плане. При этом в интересах однозначности в названиях могут появляться написания слогов, нехарактерные для русского языка (напр. сочетания "чэ", "ця" при транскрипции китайских названий), т.е. само по себе это не является нарушением норм. В "казахском" случае, как следует из работы по ссылке выше, реформа транскрипции имён основывалась исключительно на приближении к казахскому произношению, что может иметь оправдание только для казахского варианта русского языка. Судя по тому, что общепризнанного варианта казахско-русской практической транскрипции в сети нет (для большинства языков есть даже отдельные статьи википедии), к "обновлённым" вариантам названий нужно относиться с осторожностью. К сожалению, некоторые переименования (Алматы и др.) уже официально приняты.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве десерта к предыдущему ответу.
Если вы не хотите лишних проблем с документами и пластиковыми картами - лучше примите транскрипцию. 
И вот еще что вспоминается:

> Примечание. В русских фамилиях после ц пишется буква и или ы в
>   соответствии с традицией и с регистрацией в официальных документах,
>   напр.: Ципко, но Цыбин; Куницын, Курицын, Синицын, Скобельцын,
>   Солженицын, но Вицин, Ельцин, Цицин.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Ситуация понятна, но все равно вызывает недоумение, почему в русский язык вносят изменения жители других стран. Как мне кажется, РФ должна поддерживать нормы русского языка, а не идти на поводу у политики.

Answer (score 0):

На написание имен собственных большинство орфографических правил русского языка не распространяется (кроме тех, что специально под имена собственные созданы). Поэтому говорить о какой-то "неправильности" причин нет. Вопрос в целесообразности подобного прямого транслитерирования. И тут могут быть разные мнения. К сожалению, иногда политическая (дипломатическая) целесообразность перевешивает всё остальное - и указанием свыше МИД или ещё какая из властей предержащих спускает директивы по написанию на русском языке топонимов по образцу национальных языков стран, где русский даже не является государственным. С одной стороны, такое стремление понятно, это обеспечивает единообразие. Но с другой, оно же вносит путаницу в тех случаях, когда в русском есть закрепившееся собственное название.

В приведенных конкретных случаях можно остановиться на казахском написании. Шымкент, пожалуй, с долей сомнения, поскольку русский вариант топонима известен достаточно хорошо. 
Вот два более известных примера - Беларусь и Кыргызстан - вызывают реальное неприятие. Первое потому, что русское по сути своей слово записано иностранной орфографией, а второе из-за абсолютного несоответствия написания русской фонетике.